# Method 'post_title' not found in class.

Tags: debug, post-class, ide

I'm running some code through phpStorm and am getting an error:

```
Method 'post_title' not found in class.
```

at this line:

```
echo $post->post_title();
```

Is that phpStorm getting things wrong or am I accessing `post_title` incorrectly?

Comment: Can you provide more information? How do you get the `$post` object?

Answer (score 0):

Two lines of code could hide many things but I find an error: post_title is an attribute and not a method.

```
echo $post->post_title;
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post